# assetic:dump fails on "less" filter

Tags: symfony, assetic

When I try and dump my assetic managed content for a Symphony2 app, I get the following error:

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump -e prod
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  There is no "less" filter.
```

However, as far as I can tell I don't use any assets that require the less filter, certainly a grep of all my twig templates doesn't turn anything up.

One of the dependencies I've installed via composer (Twitter's bootstrap) has some .less templates, but I don't reference them in my twig templates, I just point it at the css version. Will assetic still try and dump them? How can I tell it not to?

For reference this is how I include the css in my template

```
{% stylesheets filter="cssrewrite"
  '../vendor/jquery-ui-css/jquery-ui-css/*css'
  '../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap*.css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

hm many possible causes ...

1) some third-party bundle adds an assetic collection dependeing on the less filter in a **compiler pass**

2) there is an **apply-to rule**  like

```
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            apply_to: *.less
```

... in your assetic configuration i.e. `app/config/config.yml`

3) there is an **asset collection** using less filter in your configuration

```
assetic:
    assets:
        css_character:
            inputs: 
                 - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/YourBundle/Resources/public/less/*.less"
             outputs:
                 - css/my.css
             filters:
                 - less
```

4) one of your third-party bundles provides a twig template using assetic's `{% stylesheets %}` function with the less filter:

```
{% stylesheets "@AcmeTwitterBundle/Resources/bootstrap/less/*.less" filter="less" %}
    {# ... {{ asset_url }} ...#}
{% endstylesheets %}
```

---

Now how to find out?

At first check your config files `app/config/config.yml` and other included ones for assetic entries using the less filter.

The easiest way to find out where the less filter is being used is installing [ElaoWebProfilerExtraBundle](https://github.com/Elao/WebProfilerExtraBundle), clearing your cache and having a look at the "Assetic" tab in the left-side menu of the profiler. You will get an overview of all assetic collections and the filters they use.

Another option - not involving a new bundle although WebProfilerExtraBundle is awesome - is to disable your third-party bundles one by one ( and clear the cache each time ) in `app/AppKernel.php` try if `assetic:dump` still throws the exception until you find the bad-boy.

Or dirty: enable the filter though less is probably not installed and see where the next exception is thrown:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        less: ~
```

... all in all i would bet you included the supercool mopa-bootstrap bundle of which almost nobody knows what it's actually doing behind the scenes but it's famous and many people install it because of it's KnpBundle's score.

meaning ... your exception would then be thrown because of the less files included in the templates provided by MopaBootstrapBundle i.e. [here](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/base.html.twig#L15).

Comment: It was a 3rd party library that was the problem, but it was BcBootstrapBundle instead of Mopa. Updating to the latest version also took out my dev box with the same error. In the end I installed lessphp with composer & let that handle the compile.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this saved me a lot of time. Thank you!  Lesson:  Don't assume your host/server has the ideal set ups and capabilities!